# jQuery plugin slick is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I downloaded the jQuery files to create image sliders for my Website, but it's not working at all. Can somebody teach me which codes I have problems? thank you..

```html
<body>
  <ul class="slider" "position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
        height: 300px;">
    
      <li><div class="slick"><img src="./images/sample-01.png"></div></li>
      <li><div class=""><img src="./images/sample-02.png" /></div></li>
      <li><div class="slick"><img src="./images/sample-03.png" /></div></li>
      <li> <div class="slick"><img src="./images/sample-01.png" /></div>
    <li> <div class="slick"><img src="./images/sample-02.png" /></div></li> 
      <li><div class="slick"><img src="./images/sample-03.png" /></div></li>
  </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
 var_slideshowTransitions = [
     
{$Duration:1200,$Opacity:2}
 ];
 var options={
        $SlideDuration:500,
        $AutoPlay:true,
        $DragOrientation:3,
        $Idle:1500,
        $slideshowOptions: {
            $Class:$JssorslideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions:_slideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder:1,
            $ShowLink: true
        }
                        };
                        
var slider= new $Slider$("slider", options);
                 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your HTML is poorly structured and invalid.  You didn't close your 4th `<li>` element, also, in the `<ul>` element, you have to use the `style` attribute to apply styles inline. In your case, like this:  `<ul class="slider" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;height: 300px;">`.

I have no idea where you got that Javascript code from but the [slickJS documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is pretty simple to follow.

My code below implements a slideshow which you can copy, paste and modify, if you like.  Look into the docs.  You can set or change a ton of options to help get your slider to do what you want.  Also, make sure you are importing everything in the correct order.  jQuery -> slickjs -> custom Javascript.  Make sure the slick CSS is linked in the head.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.slider').slick({
    dots:true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});
```

```css
/*
  modify the slider container with your own custom CSS
  to have it fit or placed in your page how you want.
*/
.slider {
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
/*
  I put divs inside that can have their padding modified
  so the images aren't directly up against each other.
  Feel free to play with this CSS to desired affect.
*/
.slide-image-container {
  padding:2%;
}
/*
  This CSS forces the inner images to size to the parent (slide) container
*/
.slide-image-container img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
      <div>
        <div class="slide-image-container"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg"/></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-image-container"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg"/></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-image-container"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg"/></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-image-container"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg"/></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-image-container"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg"/></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="slide-image-container"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000532546226/dbe5f0727b69487016ffd67a6689e75a.jpeg"/></div>
      </div>
</div>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
```